# Перевести код с питона на с++

Tags: python, c++

Есть код на питоне:

```
for i in range(0, len(dnk), 3):
        t += 1
        if d[dnkCopy[i:i+3]] != pep[t]:
            return False
```

И я не понимаю как написать 3 строчку на с++
d[] это у нас dictionary; dnkCopy это копия днк, в которой некоторые элементы поменяны на другие; pep эт пиптид( сторока из аминокислот)
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: `dnkCopy` это строка или список?

Comment: dnkCopy это строка

Comment: Если вы будете кодировать каждый нуклеотид одним символом и тупо использовать стандартные контейнеры, то вряд ли существенно выиграете от перехода на C++. (Насколько я понимаю, вы идете по ДНК по 3 нуклеотида (т.е. по кодонам). Эту тройку можно представлять 6-ю битами, которые и использовать как индекс в **массиве** (в питоне аналогом будет list) `d`)

Comment: почему вы вопрос дизлайкаете? он нормальный

Answer (score 0):

Аналог `str` в C++ - `std::string`, аналог `dict` - `std::map<KeyType, ValueType>`

```
for (int i = 0; i < dnk.size(); i += 3) {
    t += 1
    if (d[dnkCopy.substr(i, i + 3)] != pep[t])
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Скорее `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: а если написать `pep[++t]`, то `t += 1` можно убрать

Comment: @tocic фактически да, но тут уже зависит от типа данных, которые он собирается хранить в словаре.

Comment: @АлексейР можно, но так код более понятен

Comment: Почему? Независимо от хранимого типа, как `std::unordered_map`, так и `dict` требуют хешируемости этого типа (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash, https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable), а `std::map` не требует хешируемости, а требует сравнимости (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). Есть сторонний класс `sortedcontainers.SortedDict` с похожими сложностями операций, требующий как сравнимости, так и хешируемости ключей (https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html#sortedcontainers.SortedDict.__init__).

Comment: @tocic я это и имел ввиду. `std::unordered_map` и `std::map` накладывают разные требования к типам данных и выбор между этими двуми типами зависит только от типа, который мы будем хранить и, возможно, от каких-то предпочтений в скорости

Comment: С этим согласен. Но моя претензия к слову "аналог" в ответе. Если уж говорить про аналог `dict` в стандартном C++, то это `std::unordered_map`, а не `std::map`. И хранимый тип не делает `std::map` аналогом `dict` больше, чем он является аналогом `std::unordered_map`.